# Retrieve all tweets ever posted

Tags: java, python, twitter, twitter4j, tweets

Is there a chance I can get ALL the tweets ever posted on Twitter (I want to extract only those that contain a specific keyword)? I tried a lot of codes. For example this one https://www.socialseer.com/twitter-programming-in-java-with-twitter4j/how-to-retrieve-more-than-100-tweets-with-the-twitter-api-and-twitter4j/ but it only download maximum from 30 nov (so 10-11 days ago). I also tried in pyhton, but with the same result.

Comment: Why thumbs down? I really want to know the answer to start developing my app lol...

Comment: Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how to best use this site and how to ask questions that get positive reception and answers.

Comment: It is just a simple question, well explained.

Comment: Think about it this way, if the guys at Twitter let anyone and everyone get all the tweets ever posted they would need a ridiculously large an expensive infrastructure to support it

Comment: Your question contradicts itself.  That's why you are getting downvotes.

Comment: It looks like someone understood my question and answered nicely to it. I don't need your answers anymore, it they are not related to my question. Thank you.

Comment: And where is the contradiction? I can't take all the tweets, just the recent ones, and I want to know if there is a way to get all of them. That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pay for [Enterprise-tier access](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview) you can search the entire tweet archive going back to 2006.

Assuming you don't want to do that, search is restricted to the last 7 days (with Standard-tier access) or 30 days (with Premium-tier access). Timelines are generally [restricted to the most recent 3,200 tweets](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html).